# Show me previous data as time stamp in google sheet column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUgay.png)
I have these two columns in google sheets. Column I is data of last activity which is coming from a source report in salesforce in google sheets that automatically updates daily using a tool called Coeffecient. This date will change if there is new activity on it. What I want in column J is to show me the previous activity as a time stamp. So for example if Column I "5/15/2023" changes tomorrow to "5/26/2023", I want column J to show the previous date "5/15/2023". How can I do that?

Comment: `Column I is data of last activity which is coming from a source report in salesforce in google sheets that automatically updates daily using a tool called Coeffecient.` Does a given data record **always** appear on the same row?

Comment: With all due respect to @MattKing, there is no _formula_ that will do what you want. However, you could use a script to create the date in Column J. The script would have to be [time-driven](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) because an update in data from your "Coefficient" tool will not trigger any action.

Comment: I don't have a working knowledge of "Coeffecient" but may I elaborate on a few things. `So for example if Column I "5/15/2023" changes tomorrow to "5/26/2023", I want column J to show the previous date "5/15/2023"` The challenge is to identify 3 things: 1) that the date in Column I changed and 2) the value of the previous date BUT also 3) that the date in Column I only changed **once** since you last checked. In terms of executing the process, since script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run, a time-driven trigger seems your best option.